# Android retrofit преобразовывает параметр @Query

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

```
@GET("/users")
    fun users(
        @Query("datetime") datetime: String,
    ): Deferred<UsersResponse?>
```

Привет, суть такая, сервер ожидает получить в параметре datetime строку вида
2020-12-01T00:00:00.000%2B02:00

но улетает 2020-11-01T00%3A00%3A00.000%252B02%3A00

то-есть символ ":" замещается %3A. Как можно обойти это?
Если использовать строку пути в аннотации /users?datetime=2020-12-01T00:00:00.000%2B02:00 то отрабатывает корректно, но нужна динамика, поэтому такой вариант не подходит(

Comment: `@Query(value="datetime", encoded=true)`

Comment: @woesss , спасибо. Вылетело с головы) Пойду перечитаю документацию!))